Does this probability theory problem have a name?
I found the following problem in a step of a proof of a certain theorem.
Given a random variable $X$ with bounded expectation and $\alpha\in(0,1)$, the problem is
$$\min_{z\in \mathbb{R}}\left\{\alpha\mathbb{E}[(X-z)^+]+(1-\alpha)\mathbb{E}[(X-z)^-]\right\}$$
where $(z)^+=\max\{0,z\}$ and $(z)^-=\max\{0,-z\}$. The proof claims, without further arguments or references, that this problem has solution and that any $\alpha$-quantile of $X$ is a solution.
This might be trivial, but does it have a name? Is there any reference that introduces it?

You will most likely find useful results if you search for quantile regression, see the Wikipedia page, for a derivation (and for more references). A helpful discussion is also given here on CrossValidated.
Edit: Came across another useful post that does not use the Leibniz integral rule to take the derivative of the quantile loss function.
